# Como fazer anotação em um gráfico individual usando facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou usando a função `annotate` para tentar numerar uma figura com facet_grid, mas o número vai nos dois eixos y. Como faço para escrever em apenas um lado?
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Avi1OrBh4C0TjiyruC0ouXKNy5FG?e=B6w23z

```
library(readxl)
Dados <- read_excel("Dados.xlsx")
print(Dados)

require(tidyverse)
require(ggthemes)
graph <- ggplot(Dados,aes(x = Temp, y = Gly, shape = Accesion)) +scale_shape_manual("Biotypes", values = c(19, 5))+
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean') +
  geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', 
                width=.08, fun.args = list(mult = 1.96)) +scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 125, 25), limits = c(0, 125))+ 
  facet_grid( . ~ Year ) +annotate("text", x=0.5, y=125, label= "3") +
  labs(x = 'Harvesting time', y = 'Glyphosate')+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    text = element_text(family = 'Times'),
    legend.position = "Right", 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
graph
```

Comment: pode criar um MWE?

Comment: Olá Lucas, obrigado por responder! Editei a dúvida e inseri uma figura para exemplificar. Eu preciso numerar a figura. No entanto, com a função annotate o número vai nas duas figuras. Eu preciso que o número 3 fique apenas na esquerda

Comment: a gente precisa de uma base de dados para replicar seu problema (a base que está usando ou um exemplo equivalente). MWE é a sigla em inglês para um exemplo mínimo verificável. Veja instruções: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sou iniciante por aqui. Não sei como compartilhar os dados, tirei um print deles...

Comment: Pode, por favor, [**editar a pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/498266/edit) com a saída de `dput(Gly_72_HORAS)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(Gly_72_HORAS, 20))`?

Comment: Anexei os dados no on drive

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é criar um outro `data.frame`, adicionar apenas a informação das coordenads de texto nele e usar `geom_text` para anotar. Veja:

```r
graph<- ggplot(Dados,aes(x = Temp, y = Gly, shape = Accesion)) +scale_shape_manual("Biotypes", values = c(19, 5))+
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean') +
  geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', 
                width=.08, fun.args = list(mult = 1.96)) +scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 125, 25), limits = c(0, 125))+ 
  facet_grid( . ~ Year )
  
ann<-data.frame(Accesion="ECHCO-SR", Temp=factor("24 hours", levels=c("24 hours","72")),
                Gly=105, label="3", Year=factor("Year 1", levels = c("Year 1","Year 2")))

graph<- graph + geom_text(data = ann,label = "3")
  
graph<- graph + labs(x = 'Harvesting time', y = 'Glyphosate')+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    text = element_text(family = 'Times'),
    legend.position = "Right", 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
graph
```

Retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado! E como eu faria para alterar as coordenadas? Por exemplo, eu preciso que o número 3 fique no canto esquerdo superior do Ano 1...

Comment: é só você fazer a mudança pertinente no `data.frame` ann. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: Certo. Obrigado! Nesse caso não dá para ajustar coordenadas no eixo x?